# Spring Cloud 2021.0.4 config server cannot get github repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I try to upgrade Spring cloud from 2021.0.3 to 2021.0.4, then I got the error like this:

```
Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.config.server.git' to org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentProperties failed:

Reason: Property 'spring.cloud.config.server.git.privateKey' is not a valid private key
```

My **application.yaml** setting:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          search-paths: dev
          uri: git@github.com:myapp/config.git
          default-label: master
          force-pull: true
          passphrase: xxxxxxx
          ignore-local-ssh-settings: true
          private-key: |
            -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

this is my pom.xml setting like this:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>config</name>
    <description>config-server</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>1.32</snakeyaml.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I don't change any setting in anything, just upgrade spring cloud version from 2021.0.3 to 2021.0.4.

Comment: Can you open an issue here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config?

Please include the entire stack trace along with information about how that private key was generated.

Comment: Hi @RyanBaxter. ok, I already open an issue in there. thank you

Comment: @J.Hu can you provide link to the issue?

Comment: @delor https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/2158#issue-1382686343